# Gridding a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, scipy

The xx and yy corresponds to the vertices of 9 rectangles.
How can I obtain 4 coordinates of each rectangle as tuples?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> xx, yy = np.mgrid[0:4, 10:14]
>>> xx
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3]])
>>> yy
array([[10, 11, 12, 13],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [10, 11, 12, 13]])
>>> xx, yy = xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()
>>> xx
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
>>> yy
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 10, 11, 12, 13, 10, 11, 12, 13, 10, 11, 12, 13])
>>> lists = list(zip(xx, yy))
>>> lists
[(0, 10), (0, 11), (0, 12), (0, 13), (1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (1, 13), (2, 10), (2, 11), (2, 12), (2, 13), (3, 10), (3, 11), (3, 12), (3, 13)]
```

The coordinates of the first rectangle would be:

```
[(0, 10), (0, 11), (1, 11), (1, 10)].
```

Similarly, I want to get the coordinates of other 8 rectangles in the format "list of lists".

The order of the coordinates for a rectangle is not important.

NumPy/SciPy approach is preffered.

Comment: @BasSwinckels yes, I have done it...

Comment: outside of numpy, `itertools.product` can probably be coaxed into doing what you want. `itertools.product([0,1], [10, 11])` produces your first rectangle.

Comment: @AdamSmith Well I wanna see it!

Comment: @AdamSmith That gives [(0, 10), (0, 11), (1, 10), (1, 11)], so you will visit the corners in a 'Z' pattern, instead of clockwise.

Comment: @BasSwinckels "The order of the coordinates for a rectangle is not important."

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, without using `mgrid`:

```
x = np.arange(4)
y = np.arange(10, 14)
d = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0]]  # define order to go around rectangle here

for ix in range(len(x) - 1):
    for iy in range(len(y) - 1):
        print [(x[ix + dx], y[iy + dy]) for dx, dy in d]
```

Result:

```
[(0, 10), (0, 11), (1, 11), (1, 10)]
[(0, 11), (0, 12), (1, 12), (1, 11)]
[(0, 12), (0, 13), (1, 13), (1, 12)]
[(1, 10), (1, 11), (2, 11), (2, 10)]
[(1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 12), (2, 11)]
[(1, 12), (1, 13), (2, 13), (2, 12)]
[(2, 10), (2, 11), (3, 11), (3, 10)]
[(2, 11), (2, 12), (3, 12), (3, 11)]
[(2, 12), (2, 13), (3, 13), (3, 12)]
```

If you insist in doing it using numpy only, you could do something like this:

```
xx, yy = np.mgrid[0:4, 10:14]
top = xx[:-1,1:]
bot = xx[1:,1:]
left = yy[1:,:-1]
right = yy[1:,1:]
np.column_stack(v.ravel() 
    for v in (top, left, top, right, bot, right, bot, left))
```

The result is a single matrix, but the columns are exactly the same as the tuples you want:

```
array([[ 0, 10,  0, 11,  1, 11,  1, 10],
       [ 0, 11,  0, 12,  1, 12,  1, 11],
       [ 0, 12,  0, 13,  1, 13,  1, 12],
       [ 1, 10,  1, 11,  2, 11,  2, 10],
       [ 1, 11,  1, 12,  2, 12,  2, 11],
       [ 1, 12,  1, 13,  2, 13,  2, 12],
       [ 2, 10,  2, 11,  3, 11,  3, 10],
       [ 2, 11,  2, 12,  3, 12,  3, 11],
       [ 2, 12,  2, 13,  3, 13,  3, 12]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my given data are at the form of mgrid. So I have to go ahead from there...

Comment: In that case, you can use `(xx[ix + dx, iy + dy ], yy[ix + dx, iy + dy])` instead.

Comment: I am lost though, is't it possible to get from the way I have tried in my question, 'lists = list(zip(xx, yy))'

Comment: You could, but since you 'raveled' the `xx` and `yy` matrices, you would need something like [ravel_multi_index](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html) to get the indices into the flattened arrays. But unless you are limited by speed, you would be making it much more complicated than you need to ...

Answer (score 2):

Outside of numpy (because I don't know numpy at all...)

```
import itertools

result = [list(itertools.product((x,x+1), (y,y+1))) for 
          x,y in itertools.product(range(0,3), range(10,13))]
```

That results in

```
[[(0, 10), (0, 11), (1, 10), (1, 11)],
 [(0, 11), (0, 12), (1, 11), (1, 12)],
 [(0, 12), (0, 13), (1, 12), (1, 13)],
 [(1, 10), (1, 11), (2, 10), (2, 11)],
 [(1, 11), (1, 12), (2, 11), (2, 12)],
 [(1, 12), (1, 13), (2, 12), (2, 13)],
 [(2, 10), (2, 11), (3, 10), (3, 11)],
 [(2, 11), (2, 12), (3, 11), (3, 12)],
 [(2, 12), (2, 13), (3, 12), (3, 13)]]
```